# How to replace string with value contained in cells?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a column containing formulas as "strings", i.e. `"=+I11+I192+I245+I280"` 
I need to replace the cells (`I11`, I192`,`I245`and`I280`) ID with the content (strings) contained in the cells themselves.

Example:

```
Cell X --> "=+I11+I192+I245+I280"
Cell I11 = 'A'
Cell I192 = 'B'
Cell I245 = 'C'
Cell I280 = 'D'
```

The formula should generate `"=+A+B+C+D"`.

Comment: The word "support" suggests you are doing something and you want help, so have you tried anything? Why can't you just use Find and Replace?

Comment: Suppose it depends on what you are trying to achieve. What does "=+A+B+C+D" represent? Are you expecting a result or just a string?

Comment: Just a string with those letters containted in the cells

Comment: what happens if a cell is empty?

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
="=+" & I11 &"+" & I192 &"+" & I245 & "+" & I280
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, how about :

```
=I11 & I192 & I245 & I280
```

Or you can include spaces

```
=I11 & " " & I192
```

But straight quotes - my phone is being funny...

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>The formula should generate --> "=+A+B+C+D"</sub>

Try,

```
="=+"&textjoin("+", true, I11, I192, I245, I280)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what you will be doing with empty cells so here is draft

```
Public Sub test()
   [I11] = "A": [I192] = "B": [I245] = "C":  [I280] = "D"
   Debug.Print ConvertedString("=+I11+I192+I245+I280")
End Sub

Public Function ConvertedString(ByVal inputString As String) As Variant
    Dim arr() As String, i As Long
    On Error GoTo errHand
    If Not InStr(inputString, Chr$(43)) > 0 Then
        ConvertedString = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Exit Function
    End If

    arr = Split(inputString, Chr$(43))
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = Range(arr(i))
    Next i
    ConvertedString = Join(arr, Chr$(43))
    Exit Function
errHand:
    ConvertedString = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like

```
=INDIRECT(I11,TRUE)+INDIRECT(I192,TRUE)+INDIRECT(I245,TRUE)+INDIRECT(I280,TRUE)
```

but please note that `Indirect` is a volatile function, and can slow your calculations down if used extensively.

Comment: @SJR If in cell G1="A1" and G2 = "A2" then `=INDIRECT(G1,TRUE)+INDIRECT(G2,TRUE)` will sum up cells A1 and A2 like `=A1+A2`

Comment: Agreed, but the OP has "A", "B" etc in the cells so unless they represent named ranges/constants you can't add them up (in any case he has since clarified that he wants the actual string rather than a calculated result).

Comment: @SJR you might be right, the question was too vague when I wrote the answer. Not sure if A and B etc are only examples or actual data in the cells. We will see.

Comment: The problem is that formulas changes, so I can't only change manually. The one I gave you is only an example, but I have so many different ones with all math operators.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA (with only single delimiter):

```
Function ReplaceAddr(sInput As String, Optional sDelimiter As String = "+") As String
  Dim sArr
  Dim i As Long
  sArr = Split(sInput, sDelimiter)
  For i = 1 To UBound(sArr)
    sArr = Range(sArr(i))
  Next i
  ReplaceAddr = Join(sArr, sDelimiter)
End Function
```

From OP's comment:

> The problem is that formulas changes, so I can't only change manually. The one I gave you is only an example, but I have so many different ones with all math operators.

You can try finding cell addresses with regular expression and replace with cell's value:

```
Function ReplaceAddr2(sInput As String) As String
  Dim oRegEx As Object
  Dim oMatches As Object
  Dim i As Long, lStart As Long, lLength As Long
  Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
  oRegEx.Pattern = "[A-Za-z]{1,3}\d{1,7}"
  oRegEx.Global = True
  oRegEx.MultiLine = True
  Set oMatches = oRegEx.Execute(sInput)
  lStart = 0
  For i = 0 To oMatches.Count - 1
    lLength = oMatches(i).FirstIndex - lStart
    ReplaceAddr2 = ReplaceAddr2 & Mid$(sInput, lStart + 1, lLength) & Range(oMatches(i).Value)
    lStart = lStart + lLength + oMatches(i).length
  Next
  ReplaceAddr2 = ReplaceAddr2 & Mid(sInput, lStart + 1, Len(sInput) - lStart)
End Function
```

Pattern is 1-3 letters followed by 1-7 digits.

Both functions are not volatile - will be recalculated only when input string changes, but not when cells addressed there change. Adding this line:

```
Application.Volatile True
```

will make it recalculate on every change, but it may affect performance.